# elusive recaptcha bug. Copy code always fails

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

A very small amount of my users get a captcha that asks them to copy and paste a code, but it always fails for them - while most of the users get the normal one (checkbox) which goes through correctly.
Googling only returned three instances of people getting that captcha none of which had any valuable information

Any ideas as to why they're getting that captcha and most importantly why does it fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why this happens:

This happens when the client has JavaScript disabled. Let's take a look at the following sample code.

#### Example code from [reCAPTCHA: Tips and Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/tips) API documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
</script>

<noscript>
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
       height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
       value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

As we can see, there are `noscript` tags containing an `iframe`, a `textarea`, and a hidden `input`. When JavaScript is disabled, it will render the contents of the `noscript` tags and it will look something like this.

[image: JavaScript disabled]

The `iframe` contains a form where a user can enter the captcha and submit the form, upon which the `iframe` will load a new page containing the response code. Since JavaScript is disabled, the only way to get that token to the parent page's form is to have the user copy-and-paste the token into the `textarea` in the example.

## Workaround?:

So long as the user correctly copy-and-pastes the token, it should work fine. Double-check that the HTML for the captcha contains the correct fallback elements. You can also disable JavaScript in your browser to test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check the setup on this particular test machine and see if javascript is turned off.  I don't think that is the case but will see

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have JavaScript enabled (otherwise I wouldn't be able to post this comment). I keep failing the "Are you a human being" test. Apparently I'm actually a robot! Eventually I get the "Copy this code and paste it in the empty box below" message but doing what they ask has no effect, the page just sits there with the copied code in it. I am using Opera but that shouldn't matter, it should work on all well known, modern browsers.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderO'Mara, the link you provided is for reCaptcha 1.0, do you know if this behavior is also present in version 2.0? Also, I didn't include the <noscript> code, but some clients are getting the code to copy and paste it instead of the checkbox, is this a default behavior when Javascript is disabled?

Comment: @maxivis The reCaptcha 2.0 code does not include a `noscript` fallback, so I don't think it does, but perhaps if scripts are not allowed to load inside the appropriate iframes, you might see something like this, but I haven't investigated this and am not sure why this would happen in the first place.

Comment: @maxivis As for your second question, if you don't include the `noscript` tags, I don't see how this would be possible, as the only other code is a script tag which wouldn't run is JS were disabled. Maybe if that script runs, but other scripts fail to load/run, you might see that. Or maybe Google does this for IP addresses that are used by bots. Tough to say without a way of reproducing it.

Comment: @maxivis Another possibility might be that your users are using a browser extension like NoScript which is patching in the JS-less fallback so that they can use the captcha without enabling JS. I have no idea if any browser extensions actually do this or not though.

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexanderO'Mara for your help, regards

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've run into the same issue. It's very difficult to find any useful information about this online. I did come across this post, though: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/urgent-problem-with-cloudflare-recaptcha-and-firefox/87307/3

It has the info that I needed to finally repro the problem reliably: Setting your user agent string to `Firefox/24.0`. (This link tells you how to do that in your browser: https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/

Now the question is: How to solve the problem? When reCaptcha decides to render the "Copy this code and paste it in the empty box below" UI, it seems to deactivate all of the normal JS callbacks that it would normally invoke. It's almost as if reCaptcha "thinks" it's running in a browser that doesn't support JavaScript.

It will still render the `g-recaptcha-response` textarea in the DOM. Usually that textarea is hidden, but in this mode it's visible. It's the "box" that the user should paste the code into.

It seems to be intended to be included in whatever form data you send to your server. Since reCaptcha "thinks" that it's running in a browser that doesn't support JavaScript, it expects you to do the reCaptcha validation on the server.

However, if you still want to react to the user pasting the code into the textarea, you can simply register an event handler for the `input` event on the `g-recaptcha-response` textarea.

```
let captchaTextarea = document.querySelector("textarea[name='g-recaptcha-response']")

if (captchaTextarea) {
    captchaTextarea.addEventListener("input", () => {
        console.log("Received reCaptcha input: ", captchaTextarea.value)
    }, false)
}
```

Something along those lines.